# Control the appearance of an interstitial ad

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, interstitial

I have a problem with an interstitial so that it does not appear in the middle of the game but it appears when the player leaves and re-entered Is there a solution to show the middle of the game.

```
private ZenGL zengl;
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
private static final String IAD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
protected AdView adView;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private boolean needAds = false;

public void onAdLoaded() {
    mInterstitialAd.show();
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    if ( zengl != null )
        zengl.onResume();

    if (adView != null)
        adView.pause();

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() & (needAds==true)) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        needAds=false;
    }  
    super.onResume();
}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    //  .addTestDevice("")
    .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    needAds = true;
}
```

How do I edit these codes to show a midterm game ad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void showAd(){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

this function will show ad after 3 second ;)

Answer (score 0):

Refer the official documentation for placing the ads .
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

and if you want to show the ads in the middle of the game , one simple way is to create a separate thread , which start on start of your game and for every fixed time interval  fire the events to show the ads from the thread.